# Is there a synonym of "transcend" that has negative connotations

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, connotation

I want to say something like, "The argumentative scene in politics has transcended the once epistemological purpose of rhetoric and debate, in favor of treating rhetoric as a tool, debate as a means to an end other than truth and with a focus on winning the discussion, instead of learning from it."

Anyways, this transcendence is meant negatively, but I've pretty much only heard *transcend* in positive and/or awe-inspiring settings. Sure, there's the *transcend sanity*, but then the negative context is pretty obvious, given the negative connotations with insanity. However, that sentence there does leave it a bit ambiguous whether I think this transcendence is bad or not. Perhaps someone could get a Machiavellian feel of me and think I actually like this way of discussion. So, therefore, is there a synonym of *transcend* that has more negative connotations?

Comment: Appears to me "sidelined" could replace "trespassed" in that write-up. By the way, don't you think you are basically looking for an antonym of "transcend"?

Comment: @Stockfish Well, the way I see it, *transcend* describes the action of changing or building upon the essence of something, whilst that something superficially has changed quite a little. If one analyses that something, one sees that it's essence has been changed, usually but not necessarily an upgrade; even more substantive and deep. As such, I'd see the antonym of *transcend* as a word describing a superficial change, yet a completely generic iteration of the essence. This might just be my subjective understanding of the word.

Comment: @Stockfish I meant "...superficially changed quite little" (not "quite a little")

Answer (score 1):

Would “*... in politics has descended from the once ...*” suit your purpose?

Comment: Isn't this word already there in the definition of my suggestion ? :)

Comment: Good heavens, so it is! I have withdrawn my answer.

Comment: And changed it to what I wanted - descended. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Stockfish, "Isn't this word already there in the definition of my suggestion?" --- Yes but that doesn't make this answer a duplicate of yours and is allowed to do.

Comment: Ok, Sir @Decapitated Soul :)

Answer (score 1):

One synonym of *transcend* that is almost always used in a negative sense is [**overshoot**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overshoot):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1** : to pass swiftly beyond
> **2** : to shoot or pass over or beyond so as to miss

In other words, while *transcend* goes beyond something in a good way, *overshoot* goes ***too*** far beyond something.

Used in the example sentence:

> The argumentative scene in politics has ***overshot*** the once epistemological purpose of rhetoric and debate, in favor of treating rhetoric as a tool, debate as a means to an end other than truth and with a focus on winning the discussion, instead of learning from it.

---

Note that Merriam-Webster specifically lists [*overshoot* as a synonym of *transcend*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/transcend) in the same sense as used in the question (I have emphasized the word):

> **2** to go beyond the limit of
>    // a person who believes that any true understanding of God *transcends* human intelligence
>
> **Synonyms for** ***transcend***
> break, exceed, outreach, outrun, overpass, overreach, overrun, ***overshoot***, overstep, surpass

Of all those synonyms, *overshoot* is the only one that has both a negative connotation and sounds natural in the context of the example sentence.

Comment: My connotative understanding of *overshoot* implies **intention** for truth and then failure, instead of what I'm trying to say, intention to win the discussion. As such, it's not like they aimed at truth and missed, as I think *overshoot* implies, rather they didn't aim at truth to begin with.

Comment: @A.Kvåle I have expanded my answer to include the full definition of *overshoot* as well as support for it being used as a synonym for *transcend* in exactly the sense that you are looking for.

Comment: Well, it might definition-wise work, but connotatively it might make it seem like I think politicians have failed in the art of debate, when in reality, I'm trying to communicate that this wrongful version of debate is completely **deliberate**. I feel like the word *overshoot* misses this message (pun definitely intended).

Comment: @A.Kvåle It's the only thing that satisfies the question, as far as I can tell, as a synonym with a negative meaning which can be used naturally in the sentence. If it doesn't work, then either the question is phrased in the wrong way ("*debate being meticulously, ingeniously* ***deliberate***" says something different than what's in the question), or there simply is no word that fits.

Comment: Do you think *transcend* could be used? I mean, the negativity is pretty strongly implied later in the text, I'd say.

Comment: @A.Kvåle I've never heard *transcend* used with a negative connotation before.

Answer (score 0):

The most appropriate word I can come up with is "devolve"

> **Devolve:** to degenerate or deteriorate gradually: After several hours the discussion had devolved into a shouting match.

[American Heritage Dictionary]

Comment: I would have said 'devolve' is an _antonym_ of 'transcend' myself. It is a downwards aspect.